# Regex that will match 6 characters that only allows digits, leading, and trailing spaces

Tags: java, regex

The regex that I'm trying to implement **should match** the following data:

1. `123456`
2. `12345`
3. `23456`
4. `5`
5. `1`
6. 
7. `2`
8. `2345`

It **should not match** the following:

1. `12 456`
2. `1234 6`
3. `1   6`
4. `1    6`

It should be 6 characters in total including the digits, leading, and trailing spaces. It could also be 6 characters of just spaces. **If digits are used, there should be no space between them.**

I have tried the following expressions to no avail:

```
^\s*[0-9]{6}$
```

```
\s*[0-9]\s*
```

Comment: This should do: `\s*\d*\s*(?<=^.{6})$` = white space, digits, white space, followed by end input (`$`) which is preceded by precisely 6 characters.

Comment: @aioobe Then you should post an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @JimGarrison, haven't tested it so I'm not sure of my solution. Just wanted to mention look arounds. Feel free to test it and post it.

Comment: @Loren: is the requirement to match literal, regular spaces only, or all non-linebreak whitespace, or any whitespace?

Comment: @aioobe I have tested your expression and it worked the same as the one below.

Comment: @Loren: Yes, with `matches`, it sould work the same with the `DOTALL` mode. However, it is using a lookbehind, a construct, that is less portable than a lookahead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew only regular spaces can be used.

Comment: @Loren: I updated the answer to meet that requirement. The pattern becomes much shorter.

Comment: Why not `/^ *\d{1,6} *$/`?

Comment: How do you define *digit*? Do you only care about the 10 ASCII digits or do you want any codepoint that unicode classifies a digit?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Because that matches strings of any length.

Comment: @Loren Do you *have* to use a regex? If you're going to use this in regular code it might be neater to just check `str.length()` and then use the regex `^ *\d* *$` since some future reader of your code might not be familiar with lookarounds.

Comment: @MartinBüttner You're correct. And my regex fails the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html). The right regex would be `/^ *[0-9]{1,6} *$/`, after checking the length. That way, it may be faster since you will only try to check if the pattern matches after checking the length. That would reduce some overhead of always using the regex for everything.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just use a  `*\d* *` pattern with a restrictive `(?=.{6}$)` lookahead:

```
^(?=.{6}$) *\d* *$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB8yA8/3)

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{6}$)` - the string should only have 6 any characters other than a newline
- `*` - 0+ regular spaces (**NOTE** to match horizontal space - use `[^\S\r\n]`)
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `*` - 0+ regular spaces
- `$` - end of string.

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/lOz196) (last 4 are the test cases that should fail):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("123456", "12345 ", " 23456", "     5", // good
"1     ", "      ", "  2   ", " 2345 ",  // good
"12 456", "1234 6", " 1   6", "1    6"); // bad
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str.matches("(?=.{6}$) *\\d* *"));
```

Note that when used in `String#matches()`, you do not need the intial `^` and final `$` anchors as the method requires a full string match by anchoring the pattern by default.

Comment: You should change `\s` to `space` otherwise if there is line break it will also be considered

Comment: Use alteration to match six spaces i.e example 6. P.S: How is it matching [more than six spaces](https://www.regex101.com/r/fE7jQ5/1) ?

Comment: @rock321987: OP uses `\s`, so I suggested `\s`. To match *horizontal* spaces, one should use `[^\S\r\n]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Remarkable Exaplanation. Thanks to you. You also resolved my some of the problem raised earlier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for giving one of the most comprehensive answers I have got in stackoverflow. I'll most likely choose this answer once I tested all my test data with it.

Comment: So, does my solution pass all the test cases?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it did. Thank you for your answer. If it isn't too bothersome I'd like to ask if is there a way to know on what part of the regex did the string fail? 

For example, it exceeded the maximum length. Is there a way to know in Java? Or only through separating the regex for length and character check?

Comment: You'd need to use a different regex then (with optional capturing groups and then check what matched), or use additional non-regex checks. Regex is designed to return a match, not a non-match (in Java).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Last question, is there a way to extract from regex the maximum length that you've put in? Extract the max length as a string.

Comment: You mean, use some code to analyze a pattern and return the length(s) the pattern can match? That is impossible without parsing the pattern (and certainly it is too broad a topic to discuss here).

Answer (score 7):

You can also do:

```
^(?!.*?\d +\d)[ \d]{6}$
```

- The zero width negative lookahead `(?!.*?\d +\d)` ensures that the lines having space(s) in between digits are not selected
- `[ \d]{6}` matches the desired lines that have six characters having just space and/or digits.